# Yahoo finance API Quotes wrong date randomly - between today and yesterday days ago

Tags: yahoo-finance

I am using the yahoo finance API to get the price quotes from the market that has closed. I usually run the API at about 11pm at night (USA time). The API will return today's market data some times and yesterdays market data sometimes. It seems to be random and if you run it a few times in a row you can see it randomly switching between these dates. How can I get it to consistently return the latest quotes and not yesterday's quotes?

Comment: Just got started with their API and detected the same problem, once every dozen requests or so it answers with a quote from nearly a year ago. I suppose checking the `regularMarketTime` field helps.