# HTTP Error 404 from googlefinance in python 2.7

Tags: python, json, google-finance

In python 2.7 shell I ran the follwoings:

```
$from googlefinance import getQuotes
$import json
$from urllib2 import urlopen
$print json.dumps(getQuotes('AAPL'), indent=2)
```

Got error message on the 4th command as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  Python Shell, prompt 3, line 1
  File "C:\Users\mlashkar\_development\python\v2.7\Lib\site-packages\googlefinance\__init__.py", line 70, in getQuotes
    content = json.loads(request(symbols))
  File "C:\Users\mlashkar\_development\python\v2.7\Lib\site-packages\googlefinance\__init__.py", line 33, in request
    resp = urlopen(req)
  File "C:\Users\mlashkar\_development\python\v2.7\Lib\urllib2.py", line 154, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\mlashkar\_development\python\v2.7\Lib\urllib2.py", line 435, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Users\mlashkar\_development\python\v2.7\Lib\urllib2.py", line 548, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "C:\Users\mlashkar\_development\python\v2.7\Lib\urllib2.py", line 473, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Users\mlashkar\_development\python\v2.7\Lib\urllib2.py", line 407, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\mlashkar\_development\python\v2.7\Lib\urllib2.py", line 556, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

Not sure whats going on. 
Here is an image of my activities. 
[image]

Comment: Might be related to something recent with Google Finance's URL changes: https://github.com/hongtaocai/googlefinance/issues/39

Comment: Yeah @birryree, it seems freshly reported issue ...

Comment: I've posted an example of how to get the data directly rather than use a module, if that helps you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It seems like Google Finance modified their URLs/endpoints and the `googlefinance` package has not been updated to reflect the change.

Since most of these changes are rather opaque to end-users (and the library you're using hasn't been updated in 2 years), you might have better luck dealing with the raw Google Finance response yourself.

#### The Google Finance Endpoint

You can retrieve information about a particular ticker symbol via the following URL:

```
https://finance.google.com/finance?output=json&q=TICKER_SYMBOL
```

#### The Response

Google Finance returns JSON results in this format

```
\n// [\n{\n"symbol" : "AAPL",\n"exchange" : "NASDAQ",\n"id": "22144",\n"t" 
: "AAPL",\n"e" : "NASDAQ",\n"name" : "Apple Inc."\n, "f_reuters_url" : 
"http:\\x2F\\x2Fstocks.us.reuters.com\\x2Fstocks\\x2Fratios.asp?rpc=66\\x26symbol=AAPL.O",\n"f_recent_quarter_date" : "Q3 (Jul \\x2717)",\n"f_annual_date" : "2016",\n"f_ttm_date" : "2015",\n"financials" :

    ... a lot more stuff ...
[\n]\n}]\n'
```

It can't be loaded by Python's JSON parser as-is because it has leading `//`, and wraps everything inside `[]`. It also has Unicode-escaped characters in various strings that need to be decoded.

#### Complete code and parsing

I'm going to use the `requests` module for this, but if you want an example with the built-in `urllib` module, I can show that as well.

```
import json

import requests

rsp = requests.get('https://finance.google.com/finance?q=AAPL&output=json')

if rsp.status_code in (200,):

    # This magic here is to cut out various leading characters from the JSON 
    # response, as well as trailing stuff (a terminating ']\n' sequence), and then
    # we decode the escape sequences in the response
    # This then allows you to load the resulting string
    # with the JSON module.
    fin_data = json.loads(rsp.content[6:-2].decode('unicode_escape'))

    # print out some quote data
    print('Opening Price: {}'.format(fin_data['op']))
    print('Price/Earnings Ratio: {}'.format(fin_data['pe']))
    print('52-week high: {}'.format(fin_data['hi52']))
    print('52-week low: {}'.format(fin_data['lo52']))
```

This would output:

```
Opening Price: 162.71
Price/Earnings Ratio: 18.43
52-week high: 164.94
52-week low: 102.53
```

There is a lot more data that's included in a full ticker JSON than what I'm outputting, so it's up to you to decide how you want to use any of it.

#### Alternatives

Alternatively, you could use the [`yahoo-finance`](https://github.com/lukaszbanasiak/yahoo-finance) module, which is probably less likely to have issues like this as Yahoo still provide a real finance API.

Comment: Simply awesome @birryree!  Thanks for great details !

Comment: @birryree This endpoint does not support multiple query at one time?

Comment: @bkcollection unfortunately, no. I don't know if there's a replacement for the endpoint that the module used to use.

Comment: @birryree Thanks. Any other way that we can get a list of quotes at one query now with google?

Comment: One issues with `http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=AAPL+GOOG+MSFT&f=snbaopl1` is the time of the stock quote, will sometimes going back to the previous one after refresh, mean I get the quote at 11am, then 11.05am I refresh again but sometimes the stock quote get data for 10.50am or even back to yesterday's quote. Not sure if someone have other workaround.

Comment: There are someone point out the same issue for Yahoo finance quote over here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39177284/yahoo-finance-api-quotes-wrong-date-randomly-between-today-and-yesterday-days

Comment: Most info works, although the ticker  xxxx:1234  might have changed. Also, i don't get data yet for currency like EURUSD:CURRENCY. Still searching.

Comment: Similar issue reported, some alternate suggested there could be helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46071595/google-finance-api-for-getting-quote-has-stopped-working-today-is-there-an-alte/46073124#46073124

Comment: fin_data = json.loads(rsp.content[6:-2].decode('unicode_escape')) This has stopped working as of 20-March-2018 for NSE (India) Stocks (url - https://finance.google.com/finance?q=NSE:INFY). Seems google changed what is returned as response when you are scrapping. In browser , it still asks to save a file which has json..

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Python 3.6 or 2.7, try using:
Quandl https://www.quandl.com/
Use WIKI it seems to be stable 
example:
Apple = quandl.get('WIKI/AAPL', start_date="2016-12-31", end_date="")
Time series docs: 
https://docs.quandl.com/docs/time-series-2
If you make more than 50 requests Quandl requires a key(free to use)

Answer (score 0):

Multiple stock details working on this endpoint with google stock ID

```
https://finance.google.com/finance/data?dp=mra&output=json&catid=all&cid=13564339,5904015
```