# google finance api not working from 6/september/2017

Tags: javascript, yahoo-finance, stockquotes, google-finance-api, google-api-javascript-client

I was using google finance api to get the stock quotes and display the contents on my site. All of a sudden from 6/september/2017 this stopped working. The url i used to get the stock quotes is https://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=SYMBOL&callback=?.

Previously, i was using yahoo finance api and it was inconsistent. So, i switched over to google finance api.

Could you please help me on this?

Thanks,
Ram

Comment: The google finance API was annonced to close in 2012...

Comment: HI Salketer, Thanks for your response. I was able to fetch the data until last week, only this week i am facing this issue.

Comment: https://finance.google.com/finance?output=json&q=TICKER_SYMBOL 
   =>  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46080632/http-error-404-from-googlefinance-in-python-2-7/46081537#46081537

Comment: the above url returns text document in json format and it does not have all the data which i require for my stock ticker(it does not fetch the date and time relevant to the date)

Comment: Yeah, same happened for me.

Comment: @aldwinaldwin - how did you find that api out?

Comment: @Gishu :  from here =>  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46080632/http-error-404-from-googlefinance-in-python-2-7/46081537#46081537

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end i started using yahoo finance. The data is not live, there is a 20 minutes delay. I thought it will be helpful to people who are facing issues like me.

The yahoo api url is https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%3D%22MSFT%22&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys

This will return the stock data in xml format. You can parse the xml to get your desired fields.

Thanks,
Ram

Comment: I do not think it supports Indian stocks, does it?

Answer (score 6):

This url works. I think just the url changed from www.google.com to finance.google.com

https://finance.google.com/finance/getprices?q=ACC&x=NSE&p=15&i=300&f=d,c,o,h,l,v

Comment: This has some information, but I couldn't get the change data for the day. http://www.networkerror.org/component/content/article/1-technical-wootness/44-googles-undocumented-finance-api.html

Answer (score 2):

We had a same issue & we found below alternative API provided by Microsoft Bing API for Stock Markets. Below API returns the stock data in JSON format.

https://finance.services.appex.bing.com/Market.svc/ChartAndQuotes?symbols=139.1.500209.BOM&chartType=1d&isETF=false&iseod=False&lang=en-IN&isCS=false&isVol=true

Thanks, Shyamal

Comment: Do you know how to get the ohlc format and how to choose the time period (not resolution like 1d, 1m etc.)

Comment: Thanks Shyamal, is there an explanation of the symbol values you pass? For example, what do I pass for NSE symbols?

Answer (score 0):

I was dying to look for thread like this yesterday when I faced the issue!

Like Salketer said, Google Finance API was officially "closed" in 2012.  However, for some reason it was still working until September 5, 2017.  I built a program to manage my portfolio that uses GF API to get live quotes for US stocks.  It stopped working on Sep 6, 2017, so I am assuming that engineers behind "secretly providing" API now "actually" stopped the service.

I found an alternative https://www.alphavantage.co/documentation/ , and this seems like the best alternative for free live US equity quotes.  They just require your email, nothing else.  It's a bit slow because it doesn't have multi-symbol query yet, but beggars can't be choosers.

Comment: The link provided by you is very useful, i will have to test it today. does it provide live data?

Comment: Live data for what Google Finance would provide.  Some markets like OTC or TSE have 15 min delay.  One thing to note is that they go by minutes not seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I had to switch to Google finance after using Yahoo finance for a long time after Verizon bought yahoo this May and ended the free API service.  I went back and re-researched this issue and someone created a new Yahoo finance API call that works with the new yahoo API.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/44092983/8316350

The python source and installer can be found here: https://github.com/c0redumb/yahoo_quote_download

The arguments are (ticker, start_date, and end_date) where dates are yyyymmdd format and returns a list of unicode strings.  The following test will download a couple weeks worth of data and then extract only the adjusted close price to return a list called adj_close:

```
from yahoo_quote_download import yqd
import string
quote = yqd.load_yahoo_quote('AAPL', '20170515', '20170530')
print(quote[0]) # print the column headers
print(quote[1]) # print a couple rows of data
print(quote[2]) # just to make sure it looks right
quote.pop()  # get rid of blank string at end of data
quote = [row.encode("utf-8") for row in quote]  # convert to byte data
quote = [string.split(row, ',') for row in quote] # split the string to create a list of lists
adj_close = [row[5] for row in quote]  # grab only the 'adj close' data and put into a new list
print(adj_close)
```

Returns:

```
Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Adj Close,Volume
2017-05-15,156.009995,156.649994,155.050003,155.699997,155.090958,26009700
2017-05-16,155.940002,156.059998,154.720001,155.470001,154.861862,20048500
['Adj Close', '155.090958', '154.861862', '149.662277', '151.943314', '152.461288', '153.387650', '153.198395', '152.740189', '153.268112', '153.009140', '153.068893']
```

Answer (score 0):

I was manually reading from Google Finance page for each stock before I got the `?info` link. As this is not working anymore, I am going back to the webpage.

Here is my python snippet:

```
def get_market_price(symbol):
    print "Getting market price: " + symbol

    base_url = 'http://finance.google.com/finance?q='

    retries = 2

    while True:
        try:
            response = urllib2.urlopen(base_url + symbol)
            html = response.read()
        except Exception, msg:
            if retries > 0:
                retries -= 1
            else:
                raise Exception("Error getting market price!")

        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

        try:
            price_change = soup.find("div", { "class": "id-price-change" })
            price_change = price_change.find("span").find_all("span")
            price_change = [x.string for x in price_change]

            price = soup.find_all("span", id=re.compile('^ref_.*_l$'))[0].string
            price = str(unicode(price).encode('ascii', 'ignore')).strip().replace(",", "")

            return (price, price_change)
        except Exception as e:
            if retries > 0:
                retries -= 1
            else:
                raise Exception("Can't get current rate for scrip: " + symbol)
```

Example:

```
Getting market price: NSE:CIPLA
('558.55', [u'+4.70', u'(0.85%)'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply parse the result of this request:

https://finance.google.com/finance/getprices?q=GOOG&x=NASD&p=1d&i=60&f=d,c,o,h,l,v

(GOOG at NASDAQ, one day, frequency 60 seconds, DATE,CLOSE,HIGH,LOW,OPEN,VOLUME)

Comment: cain u please tell me best way to call this API? And is this possible to call multiple indexes separated by comma in this API?

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem in PHP.

I replace the URL https://www.google.com/finance/converter?a=$amount&from=$from_Currency&to=$to_Currency

to

https://finance.google.com/finance/converter?a=1&from=$from_Currency&to=$to_Currency

Works fine for me.

Comment: Hi surya, can you give an example with a stock symbol?