# No name 'getQuotes' in module 'googlefinance'pylint(no-name-in-module)

Tags: python

I can't run this program. I am using Anaconda3.

File Name
get_googlefinance.py

Referred Site
https://pypi.org/project/googlefinance/

Source

```
from googlefinance import getQuotes
import json

print(getQuotes('AAPL')[0]['LastTradePrice'])
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: This might solve your problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46080632/http-error-404-from-googlefinance-in-python-2-7)

Comment: Where are you seeing this error? Can you add the stack trace? As per the title it seems `pylint` is raising this warning and that shouldn't stop you from executing the code.